# Jodatime with hibernate 4.1 and annotations

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I am using Hibernate 4.1.18 with postgresql 9.1.

How do I use read/write joda DateTime objects with hibernate? I found out I should use the "Usertype" project (http://usertype.sourceforge.net/) but I can't find any documentation there.

I am using annotations with hibernate, so my class looks something like:

```
@Entity @SequenceGenerator(name="customer_id_seq",sequenceName="customer_id_seq")
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private DateTime created; // This is the jodatime object.

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="customer_id_seq")
    @Override public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // This does not work out of the box.
@Override public DateTime getCreated() {
    return created;
}
@Override  public void setCreated(DateTime created) {
    this.created=created;
}
}
```

Comment: How can't you find any documentation? There is a big "Documentation" box at the top left of the page.

Comment: I meant documentation which mentions how to make it work with hibernate. The only thing which I could find which contains anything remotely like what I need is http://usertype.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html but is it that Simple. Do I just need to add @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentLocalDateTime") (Except I would need PersistentDateTime, because my timestamp is without timezone).

Comment: Yes, it's that simple. Except the type to use is org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime.

Comment: The current version of jadira usertype fails with a NoSuchMethodError referring to part of the hibernate configuration API.  Other Hibernate APIs that my code uses have changed so upgrading will be somewhat more time consuming than I would ideally like.  Can somebody point me to the latest version of usertype that supports Hibernate 4.1?